# How to access Bing Map Metadata in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, metadata, bing-maps

Is there any way to access the metadata of Bing Maps in ArcGIS desktop? Any good plug-in or extension?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?  You need to be aware that [**complimentary use of Bing Maps is being phased out of ArcGIS products by December 31, 2013**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline-content/index.html#//011q0000001q000000).

Answer (score 1):

Click the tiny chip at the bottom right corner of the map that has Bing data to get metadata for that extent.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link
 http://goto.arcgisonline.com/maps/World_Imagery

It is mentioned in the Layer Properties under the General tab.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  I followed your link but did not find any mention of Bing Maps there.  Would you be able to use the edit button beneath your answer to provide more details about how it addresses the question, please?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the drop down arrow beside the Add data icon on the standard toolbar. The base map  imagery is Bing.

Comment: the OP is asking about Bing Maps metadata, not the imagery itself.  I would assume that the OP has added the imagery like you have described above, but now wants to extract metadata from the imagery such as "Imagery Date".